# Why game lagging?

Tags: games, steam, vulkan

i played in dota 2 at Windows perfectly, but at linux (Manjaro, Arch, Ubuntu, Linux mint and Fedora) it's lagging, fps dropping and frametime jumping + some issues with grass textures.
Game on SSD (Filesystem: EXT4) Fedora at other SSD (Filesystem: BTRFS).
My PC:
CPU: i3-8100
GPU: AMD RX580 4GB
RAM: 16GB

All updates installed.

I record video with mangohud.

[video](https://youtu.be/HQj58sSktv0)

Comment: Games written for DirectX tend to perform better in Windows.

Comment: This isn't a Linux support site, so why ask here?  You mention 6 OSes and 5 of them are off-topic here, I suggest you read https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *Fedora is not Ubuntu or flavor of Ubuntu*

Comment: The steam community forums are the place to start, should be a linux section.  Are you running it natively or using Proton?  If you are running Proton, use the native version.  It looks like vsync is enabled which is capping your fps at 60.

Comment: @guiverc ok, ty

Comment: @rtaft I'm using native version at Vulkan API.
Ok, ask about it in steam community, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so in my windows, TF2 runs smoothly. But in linux it's all choppy. So this time I installed Garuda Linux KDE gaming edition.
Then through Lutris I installed the Proton version of TF2. Now it's all smooth (unlike in the previous distros).

[Pc specs:-
• Intel Pentium
• 4gb ram
• 298 gb HDD
• No graphics card installed]